# Another way to call method without lodash?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, lodash

In my Meteor app, this voting function with a method call was working fine, until I included a compability script that exports lodash as `var _ = runInContext();` Now I get error that `_.contains` is not a function.

Is there another way to run this function and call without `_.contains`?

On button click:

```
"click [data-action='addLikes']": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var song = Songs.findOne({_id: this._id});
    upvote(song);
}
```

Server method:

```
upvote = function(currentSong){
  var user = Meteor.user();
  if(!user){
    return false;
  }
  if (currentSong) {
    if (_.contains(currentSong.voters, Meteor.userId())) {
      return false;
    }
    Songs.update(currentSong._id, {$addToSet: {voters: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {likes: 1}});
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `currentSong.voters` is just an array, you can go with two solutions:

**ES6**:

```
currentSong.voters.includes(Meteor.userId())
```

**ES5**:

```
currentSong.voters.indexOf(Meteor.userId()) > -1
```

or a shorthand

```
~currentSong.voters.indexOf(Meteor.userId())
```

Comment: Oh, easier than I would imagine. Worked as described, thank you!